# Why does my React App only look fine in a fresh tab?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am working with React and Ionic: `"@ionic/react": "^5.5.0"`. The app looks fine in a fresh tab:

[image]

As soon I hit refresh on the browser the inputs get broken/look different:

[image]

Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not seeing at a glance what appears broken with the lower image? Colors are slightly different, but that's all

Comment: In this case in the second picture you see the inputs look different. But actually many other things are broken. Why is this happening?

Comment: it looks like it is shifting between an ios and android ui, would need to see some code

Comment: @Aaron Saunders You may be on the right path. I tried it on my Android Smartphone and it works fine. The issue seems to exist only on the pc. I will check the tab storage today, probaly there is some value stored about the device.

Comment: its probably picking up the device viewport, like Android or iOS.
Is there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

It depends from variables scss on preferred dark mode that usually Ionic put automatically. You can look for "@dark" on your scss files and edit it!

Comment: It has indeed something to do with the dark mode. Actually I am happy with scss variables provided by Ionic. I just dont want the browser to change the styling on refresh.